# XSL template optional

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one data file which is called by various stylesheets. I added the line for `outputChannel` in the template letterhead.

```
<xsl:template name="letterhead">
    <xsl:call-template name="outputChannel"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="receiverAddress"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="fields06"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="letterReference"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="reference1"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="reference2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

`outputChannel` is only used in one of the stylesheets, I receive following error in the other stylesheets:

> Template 'outputChannel' not defined in this stylesheet.! Info: no additional info Category: CONFIGURATION

So I guess the `outputChannel` is a mandatory field. Is there a possibility to set the `outputChannel` in the data file to optional?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't call a template that is not defined, like you can't call a function or procedure in most other languages if it is not defined. The context is not clear from your single snippet, in general, if processing depends on input nodes it is in my view often easier to use `apply-templates` instead of `call-template`, as `apply-templates` will simply not do anything for not existing input nodes.

Comment: The template is only defined in stylesheet1, the XML creation is successful here . But for stylesheet2, where outputChannel is not defined I receive the error from above. I can understand why I receive the error. OutputChannel should not be used for stylesheet2.